# `g++ compile error :invalid initialization of reference of type, std::stod()

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, g++

I'm going to install some packages but I got errors in `std::stod( )` method.

My system is Cent OS. I installed GCC 6.2 version with `contrib/download_prerequisites` in gcc-6.2.0 directory (gmp-4.3.2, isl-0.15, mpc-0.8.1, mpfr-2.4.2)
And I have boost-1.62

This is my gcc configure option
`./gcc-6.2.0/configure -v --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr/local/gcc-6.2 --enable-checking=release --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran --disable-multilib --program-suffix=-6.2`

So, this is now my installation flow about what I  wanna install a package.

```
[root@cms CASMcode-0.2.0]# scons install
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
rm /usr/local/include/casm
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
Install directory: "include/casm" as "/usr/local/include/casm"
/usr/local/gcc-6.2/bin/g++-6.2 -o src/casm/external/gzstream/gzstream.os -c -DNDEBUG -O3 --std=c++11 -Wno-deprecated-register -Wno-deprecated-declarations -DEIGEN_DEFAULT_DENSE_INDEX_TYPE=long -Wno-unused-parameter -DNDEBUG -O3 -DGZSTREAM_NAMESPACE=gz -fPIC -Iinclude/casm/external/gzstream src/casm/external/gzstream/gzstream.C
cd src/casm/version && sed -e "s|MY_VERSION|0.2.0|g" < version_template.cc > version.cc
/usr/local/gcc-6.2/bin/g++-6.2 -o src/casm/version/version.os -c -DNDEBUG -O3 --std=c++11 -Wno-deprecated-register -Wno-deprecated-declarations -DEIGEN_DEFAULT_DENSE_INDEX_TYPE=long -Wno-unused-parameter -DNDEBUG -O3 -DGZSTREAM_NAMESPACE=gz -fPIC -Iinclude src/casm/version/version.cc
/usr/local/gcc-6.2/bin/g++-6.2 -o src/casm/CASM_global_definitions.os -c -DNDEBUG -O3 --std=c++11 -Wno-deprecated-register -Wno-deprecated-declarations -DEIGEN_DEFAULT_DENSE_INDEX_TYPE=long -Wno-unused-parameter -DNDEBUG -O3 -DGZSTREAM_NAMESPACE=gz -fPIC -Iinclude -I/usr/local/boost_1_62_0/include src/casm/CASM_global_definitions.cc
```

**Here is the where error message occured**

```
In file included from include/casm/casm_io/DataFormatterTools.hh:1291:0,
                 from include/casm/casm_io/DataFormatter_impl.hh:3,
                 from include/casm/casm_io/DataFormatter.hh:757,
                 from include/casm/clex/ConfigIO.hh:4,
                 from src/casm/clex/ConfigIOStrucScore.cc:6:
include/casm/casm_io/DataFormatterTools_impl.hh: In member function 'bool CASM::DataFormatterOperator<ValueType, ArgType, DataObject>::parse_args(const string&)':
include/casm/casm_io/DataFormatterTools_impl.hh:32:33: error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'const wstring& {aka const std::__cxx11::basic_string<wchar_t>&}' from expression of type 'std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}'
             val = std::stod(ttag);
```

Similar errors happened the following codes `std::stol(tag)`

**And finally the installation process is stopped with this message**

```
At global scope:
cc1plus: warning: unrecognized command line option '-Wno-deprecated-register'
scons: *** [src/casm/clex/ConfigIOStrucScore.os] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

I'm not familiar with C++ but I heard that `std::sto()` is some kind of data type changer.
But I don't know how to fix it. I thought that these errors come from old gcc version. But how it happens?

This is `include/casm/casm_io/DataFormatterTools_impl.hh:` file.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include "casm/external/boost.hh"
namespace CASM {

  template<typename ValueType, typename ArgType, typename DataObject>
  bool DataFormatterOperator<ValueType,
       ArgType,
  DataObject>::parse_args(const std::string &_args) {

    if(_args.size() == 0)
      return true;
    if(!m_arg_formatter.empty())
      return false;

    std::vector<std::string> format_tags, subexprs;
    split_formatter_expression(_args, format_tags, subexprs);

    //std::cout << "_args: " << _args << "\n";
    //std::cout << "format_tabs: " << format_tags << "\n"
    //<< "subexprs: '" << subexprs << "'\n";
    for(Index i = 0; i < format_tags.size(); i++) {
      std::string ttag(format_tags[i].size(), ' ');
      std::transform(format_tags[i].cbegin(), format_tags[i].cend(), ttag.begin(), tolower);

      char ch = ttag[0];
      if(boost::is_any_of("-+.0123456789")(ch)) { // tag is a constant number
        if(std::any_of(ttag.cbegin(),
                       ttag.cend(),
                       boost::is_any_of(".e"))) {
          double val;
          try {
            val = std::stod(ttag);
          }
          catch(...) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Unable to parse '" + ttag + "' from subexpression " + _args + "\n");
          }
          m_arg_formatter.push_back(ConstantValueFormatter<double, DataObject>(ttag, val));
        }
```

I have spent very long time to install this package but I couldn't. Please, help me..

*Similar example from comment*

File

```
#include <string>


int main() {
    std::string str("1.23");
    double v = std::stod(str);
    (void) v;
    return 0;
}
```

Error message

```
[root@cms ~]# /usr/local/gcc-6.2/bin/g++-6.2 -c -DNDEBUG -O3 --std=c++11 -Wno-deprecated-register -Wno-deprecated-declarations -DEIGEN_DEFAULT_DENSE_INDEX_TYPE=long -Wno-unused-parameter -DNDEBUG -O3 -DGZSTREAM_NAMESPACE=gz -fPIC test.cc
test.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cc:6:29: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘const wstring& {aka const std::__cxx11::basic_string<wchar_t>&}’ from expression of type ‘std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}’
     double v = std::stod(str);
                             ^
In file included from /usr/local/gcc-6.2/include/c++/6.2.0/string:52:0,
                 from test.cc:1:
/usr/local/gcc-6.2/include/c++/6.2.0/bits/basic_string.h:5548:3: note: in passing argument 1 of ‘double std::__cxx11::stod(const wstring&, std::size_t*)’
   stod(const wstring& __str, size_t* __idx = 0)
   ^~~~
At global scope:
cc1plus: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-deprecated-register’
```

Comment: The issue is that somehow the `wstring` overloaded version of  `stod` is getting called instead of `string` version. You can probably do `#define _GLIBCXX_USE_C99_STDLIB` in your file and see what happens

Comment: Do you mean that add `#define _GLIBCXX_USE_C99_STDLIB` on top of my error file ? `/usr/local/gcc-6.2/include/c++/6.2.0/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/c++config.h:569:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 # define _GLIBCXX_USE_C99_STDLIB _GLIBCXX11_USE_C99_STDLIB
` But the errors still happen..

Comment: Are you getting the same error if you compile a test code ? Something like http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eae3697057d101f0

Comment: Yes it is. I add its result in main text.

Comment: Ok, so who built g++ on this machine ? Is it the one installed by default ? I am sure this code compiles fine on default installed g++. I guess it probably relates to some configuration options using which the compiler was built.

Comment: Just for testing you can also try adding `#undef _GLIBCXX_USE_WCHAR_T` just before the line where you are using `stod`

Comment: Initially, gcc-4.4.7 built in this machine. And I installed gcc-6.2.0 in `/usr/local`. The same error happened even if add `#undef _GLIBCXX_USE_WCHAR_T` before line `std::stod`. Is there some libraries what I missing?  Some on told me that what if use `strtod` instead of `stod`. Then error message `error: cannot convert ‘std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}’ to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘double strtod(const char*, char**)’
     double v = std::strtod(str);` occured

Comment: If `strtod` is fine for you then use it like `strtod(str.c_str, nullptr)`

Comment: This is configure option when I install gcc-6.2.0 `Configured with: ../gcc-6.2.0/configure -v --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr/local/gcc-6.2 --enable-checking=release --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran --disable-multilib --program-suffix=-6.2`